# Changing mysql query to return always results

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query which checks for related(similar) to the shown one products and if there any it will show them. How to change it so if there aren't any related(similar) products to show other products. Here is the query:

```
select p.id,bg_product_name,unique_name,product_price,
promo_price, promo_end_date, available_qty,model,ptc.category_id, free_delivery, free_option
from products p, related_products rp, products_to_categories ptc where
 rp.product_id="10284" and rp.related_id=p.id and p.id=ptc.product_id and
 p.available_qty > 0 AND p.active="1" group by p.id limit 5
```

Thank you for any help and suggestions !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    p.id,bg_product_name,unique_name,product_price, promo_price, promo_end_date, 
    available_qty,model,ptc.category_id, free_delivery, free_option
FROM 
    products p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN products_to_categories ptc ON p.id=ptc.product_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN related_products rp ON rp.related_id=p.id AND rp.product_id="10284"

WHERE
    p.available_qty > 0 AND p.active="1" 
GROUP BY p.id LIMIT 5
```

Comment: #mynawaz why when I add order by rp.related_id or whatever else I try to order first to see related products it doesn't work?

Comment: this may depend on your data or grouping, can you share some sample data and what you've tried

Answer (score 1):

Use left join and put " rp.product_id="10284"" condition as join condition not in where.

like 
products p left Join related_products rp ON rp.related_id=p.id AND rp.product_id="10284"

follow with full query.